# How to create catch-all route in svelteKit api dir?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I am creating API endpoints in sveltekit. All API endpoints are inside `/src/routes/api/` DIR.

How can I create master catch-all routes for any `GET`, `POST`, `DELETE` & `PUT` request that don't exist?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found my answer after looking at [sveltekit repo](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/blob/main/packages/kit/test/apps/basics/src/routes/src/%5B...anything%5D/%2Bserver.js)

I have been using svelteKit version `1.30.3`. Here's how we can create catch-all routes.

1. Under `/src/routes/api/` create a dir with name `[...anything]`
2. Create `+server.ts` or `+server.js` inside `[...anything]` DIR.

Inside `+server` file.

```
import { json } from "@sveltejs/kit";
import type { RequestHandler } from "@sveltejs/kit";

export async function GET(event: RequestHandler): Promise<Response> {
    return json({
        success: false,
        code: "404",
        message: "Oops! the requested API endpoint doesn't exists!",
    });
}
```